# How to order by frequency from highest to lowest

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the goal is to open this twitter file with tweets and order the hashtags by frequency to tell the trending topics, i already asked this before but ive changed my code a bit and got to the point where it is printing the hashtags and the amount, but how would i order this and send it to another file called trending.txt

```
counts ={}
with open("/Users/Adnan/Desktop/twitter_data.txt") as data:
    for tag in data:
        for line in data:
            for part in line.capitalize().split():
                if "#" in part:
                    counts[part] = counts.get(part,0) + 1

for w in counts:
    print((w+','+str(counts[w])+'/n'))
```

Comment: @Smac89: this is sorting by *value*, in reverse order. Moreover, this comprises a counting operation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [*Counter*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dict with [*most_common*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)  lib to write the data to your outfile:

```
from collections import Counter
import csv


with open("/Users/Adnan/Desktop/twitter_data.txt") as data, open("trending.txt") as out:
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    counts = Counter(part for tag in map(str.capitalize, data)
                     for part in data.split()
                         if "#" in part)
    wr.writerows(counts.most_common())
```

Using `map(str.capitalize, data)` will map `str.capitalize` on all the lines which will be more efficient than repeatedly calling in your loop, writerows takes an iterable of iterables so it will write the  `tag, count` tuples returned from most_common to each line of your outfile.

Comment: thank you this helped quick question though in some of the posts theyll have #BULLYING and #bullying how would i got about counting them as the same hashtag? idk if the .captalize() is working correctly

Comment: @Rashid, it should be working as is, if you add a sample of the file I will have a look

Comment: @Rashid,  No worries.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a dictionary, use a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter); it is a specialised dictionary that contains your desired functionality out of the box:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
with open("/Users/Adnan/Desktop/twitter_data.txt") as data:
    for tag in data:
        for line in data:
            for part in line.capitalize().split():
                if "#" in part:
                    counts[part] += 1

with open('trending.txt') as trending:
    for hashtag, count in counts.most_common():
        print(hashtag, count, sep=',', file=trending)
```

The [`Counter.most_common()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) produces `(key, count)` values in sorted order, from most frequent to least. You can limit the number of entries returned by passing in an integer:

```
with open('trending.txt') as trending:
    # The 10 most popular hashtags
    for hashtag, count in counts.most_common(10):
        print(hashtag, count, sep=',', file=trending)
```

Note that your `for tag in data` will only iterate *once*; it'll read the first line, after which `for line in data:` processes the rest of the  file. You could use `next(data, None)` instead of that loop:

```
with open("/Users/Adnan/Desktop/twitter_data.txt") as data:
    tag = next(data, None)  # read the first line
    for line in data:
        for part in line.capitalize().split():
            if "#" in part:
                counts[part] += 1
```

Last but not least, if you are trying to produce a CSV file (comma-separated data), use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open('trending.txt') as trending:
    writer = csv.csvwriter(trending)
    writer.writerows(counts.most_common())
```

The above writes all counts, in sorted order, to the CSV file.